# Asynchronous API and callback

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, asynchronous

I have to use one asynchronous service. Everything I can do is send data to this service (I'm doing it with `PHP` and `CURL`) and send data to some url from this service. How can I react/wait for a response from this service?
Now **I have** two pages: first is sending data to service and the second takes a response from this service and inserts it to database. On a first page I'm checking some table while there isn't the response. But selecting from database few times per second is bad idea. But what **I need to have**: Send data from one page and get the response at the same page. I guess I can use some Ajax and make the async service sending data to the same page and wait for the response on this page.

I guess I wrote very hard because I can't fully explain what I need, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: php has no concept of asynchronousity. Also what do you mean by an asynchronous service? is this a webservice, that accepts a callback endpoint or something?

Comment: @Steve I know that PHP hasn't concept of async, so I noticed that I guess I have to use Ajax. Yes this is web service that can get some data and send the result to some url after the process is finished

Comment: _I have two pages: first is sending data to service and the second takes a response from this service and inserts it to database_ Why two? Does the service respond too slow?

Comment: @hindmost Really I just don't know how to recieve data from the service. It takes about 5seconds, and it just can send some data to my URL. But how do I get it on my side?

Comment: @Steve.B Now I see. So the service use callbacks to respond?

Comment: @hindmost Yes I guess

Answer (score 1):

As @Steve noted, PHP has no concept of asynchronousity. However there is a hack which allows to implement something similar to long-polling in PHP. The main point is to use a file ready to read in Javascript, i.e. JSON.

Here is a general flow:

1. Your single web page does AJAX request to your php script which send
   appropriate request to the external service and immediately return
   some response (e.g. empty) to the web page.
2. The web page starts to repeatedly request server for the same static
   JSON file (by doing AJAX requests) until it appears (created by
   callback script).
3. The external service passes response to your callback script which
   save the response into the JSON file.
4. The web page get the response from the JSON file and outputs it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but using files is very bad idea for me. Can't I recieve data on a fly? So what I decided to do: when I send request to external service I'm getting some `task_id` and when data comes from external service to my script I use ajax to wait, while data with this task_id comes. But so far I don't know how to realise this

Comment: @Steve.B _using files is very bad idea for me_ Why is it bad? Can you clarify? You cannot wait for response in the script initiating request to the service since the response will come to another script (callback script).

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest option is going to be ajax polling - send the request to the webservice, then poll every x seconds. The response handler (the script called by the webservice when it completes) need to save the data somewhere, eg database or session, and the poll script will check for this data.

Although this will add a little to server load, if you set the polling interval high enough it should be fine

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['sendrequest'])){

    WebService:sendRequest(['callback_url'=>'thispage?receiveresponse=1'])
    $_SESSION['response']=false;
    die();
}elseif(isset($_GET['receiveresponse'])){

    $response = WebService:receive();
    $_SESSION['response'] = $response;
    die();

}elseif(isset($_GET['checkresponse'])){

    $data=[];
    if($_SESSION['response']){
        $data['success']=true;
        $data['response']=$_SESSION['response'];
    }else{
        $data['success']=false;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode($data);
}
<html>
  <head>....</head>
  <body>

  <a id="send" href="#">Send Request</a>
  <div id="response"></div>

  <script>
       var poll;
       $('#send').click(function(ev){
           ev.preventDefault();
           $post('?sendrequest=1', {...}, function(){
                poll = setInterval(function(){
                    $get('?checkresponse=1', function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            clearInterval(poll);
                            $('#response').html(response.response);
                        }
                    });
                }), 3000);
           });
        });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```